# Is this plant a Dracaena fragrans?

Tags: identification, indoors, dracaena

I am having this plant for a really long time now and had to cut it back, after it was growing above 1m and only having some leaves at the top.

[image: Cutted Parts in vase]

I put the cutted parts  and some of the leaveless parts (divided them into smaller pieces) into a vase. The plant now is growing well, but sometimes some leaves get yellow or geht some brown tips.

Now I want to know, which kind of plant it is?

[image: Children in a vase]

I did some research and I guess it could be some kind of Dragon Tree. May be a *Dracaena fragrans*.

But I am not sure, since my other *Dracaena fragrans* have more leaves and are not that high and more wider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is Dracaena fragrans. This is probably the [cultivar Janet Craig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_fragrans#Cultivars).  Although the botanists have been busy reclassifying this it used to be known as Dracaena demerensis and may still be sold as this.

All the Dracaena are vulnerable to chloride and fluoride in water so I recommend using filtered water to avoid the necrotic dead spots on the leaves.

This plant buds out easily from old growth. You can take stems and stick them in the soil and they will slowly root.  Water propagation will work as well.

Bright filtered light and regularly top dressing with new soil less mix on a yearly basis are recommended.